# customize taxonomy Page

Tags: custom-taxonomy

is there a solution to customize taxonomy page 
and make it like categories page with a Title h1 and customize Sidebar?

this is my taxonomy code :

```
register_taxonomy('director', 'post', array(
'hierarchical' => false,  'label' => 'Realisateur',
'query_var' => true, 'rewrite' => $rewrite2));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on how your theme handles Taxonomy pages. If it e.g. has a `category.php` that does stuff different than `taxonomy.php` or `archive.php` this is the reason.

Have a look [here to see how the template hierarchy works](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).